# Android: how to get rows between to tags using jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I have the following html

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="6" class="sumheadtop"> Friday 18 March 2016</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="6" class="sumheadbot">&nbsp;PASSENGER ARRIVALS | DOMESTIC &amp; INTERNATIONAL | All Airlines | ALL OriginS</td>
</tr>
<tr class="schedulerow" style="height:2px"><td colspan="6"></td></tr>
<tr class="schedulerow" valign="top">
    <td class="airline"><img src="/webfids/images/3u.gif" width="100" height="24" vspace="0" alt="Sichuan Airlines"/></td>
    <td class="flight" nowrap>3U 8989</td>
    <td class="city">Chengdu</td>
    <td class="time">19:00</td>
    <td class="estimated">20:01</td>
    <td class="status"><div class="statusone">LANDED</div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="schedulerow" style="height:2px"><td colspan="6"></td></tr>
<tr class="schedulerowtwo" style="height:2px"><td colspan="6"></td></tr>
<tr class="schedulerowtwo" valign="top">
    <td class="airline"><img src="/webfids/images/q2.gif" width="100" height="24" vspace="0" alt="Maldivian"/></td>
    <td class="flight" nowrap>Q2 107</td>
    <td class="city">Gan</td>
    <td class="time">19:35</td>
    <td class="estimated">19:30</td>
    <td class="status"><div class="statusone">LANDED</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="6" class="sumheadtop"> Saturday 19 March 2016</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="6" class="sumheadbot">&nbsp;PASSENGER ARRIVALS | DOMESTIC &amp; INTERNATIONAL | All Airlines | ALL OriginS</td>
</tr>
<tr class="schedulerow" style="height:2px"><td colspan="6"></td></tr>
<tr class="schedulerow" valign="top">
    <td class="airline"><img src="/webfids/images/3u.gif" width="100" height="24" vspace="0" alt="Sichuan Airlines"/></td>
    <td class="flight" nowrap>3U 8989</td>
    <td class="city">Chengdu</td>
    <td class="time">19:00</td>
    <td class="estimated">20:01</td>
    <td class="status"><div class="statusone">LANDED</div></td>
</tr>
<tr class="schedulerow" style="height:2px"><td colspan="6"></td></tr>
<tr class="schedulerowtwo" style="height:2px"><td colspan="6"></td></tr>
<tr class="schedulerowtwo" valign="top">
    <td class="airline"><img src="/webfids/images/q2.gif" width="100" height="24" vspace="0" alt="Maldivian"/></td>
    <td class="flight" nowrap>Q2 107</td>
    <td class="city">Gan</td>
    <td class="time">19:35</td>
    <td class="estimated">19:30</td>
    <td class="status"><div class="statusone">LANDED</div></td>
</tr>
```

I want to get the rows between two "sumheadtop" class.

How do i achieve this using Jsoup

i tried using the below code but I am getting all the rows below the first "sumheadtop" class

```
doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
date = doc.select("td[class=sumheadtop]");
siblings = date.first().parent().siblingElements();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String html = "<table><tr>\n <td colspan=\"6\" class=\"sumheadtop\"> Friday 18 March 2016</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n <td colspan=\"6\" class=\"sumheadbot\">&nbsp;PASSENGER ARRIVALS | DOMESTIC &amp; INTERNATIONAL | All Airlines | ALL OriginS</td>\n</tr>\n<tr class=\"schedulerow\" style=\"height:2px\"><td colspan=\"6\"></td></tr>\n<tr class=\"schedulerow\" valign=\"top\">\n <td class=\"airline\"><img src=\"/webfids/images/3u.gif\" width=\"100\" height=\"24\" vspace=\"0\" alt=\"Sichuan Airlines\"/></td>\n <td class=\"flight\" nowrap>3U 8989</td>\n <td class=\"city\">Chengdu</td>\n <td class=\"time\">19:00</td>\n <td class=\"estimated\">20:01</td>\n <td class=\"status\"><div class=\"statusone\">LANDED</div></td>\n</tr>\n<tr class=\"schedulerow\" style=\"height:2px\"><td colspan=\"6\"></td></tr>\n<tr class=\"schedulerowtwo\" style=\"height:2px\"><td colspan=\"6\"></td></tr>\n<tr class=\"schedulerowtwo\" valign=\"top\">\n <td class=\"airline\"><img src=\"/webfids/images/q2.gif\" width=\"100\" height=\"24\" vspace=\"0\" alt=\"Maldivian\"/></td>\n <td class=\"flight\" nowrap>Q2 107</td>\n <td class=\"city\">Gan</td>\n <td class=\"time\">19:35</td>\n <td class=\"estimated\">19:30</td>\n <td class=\"status\"><div class=\"statusone\">LANDED</div></td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n <td colspan=\"6\" class=\"sumheadtop\"> Saturday 19 March 2016</td>\n</tr>\n<tr>\n <td colspan=\"6\" class=\"sumheadbot\">&nbsp;PASSENGER ARRIVALS | DOMESTIC &amp; INTERNATIONAL | All Airlines | ALL OriginS</td>\n</tr>\n<tr class=\"schedulerow\" style=\"height:2px\"><td colspan=\"6\"></td></tr>\n<tr class=\"schedulerow\" valign=\"top\">\n <td class=\"airline\"><img src=\"/webfids/images/3u.gif\" width=\"100\" height=\"24\" vspace=\"0\" alt=\"Sichuan Airlines\"/></td>\n <td class=\"flight\" nowrap>3U 8989</td>\n <td class=\"city\">Chengdu</td>\n <td class=\"time\">19:00</td>\n <td class=\"estimated\">20:01</td>\n <td class=\"status\"><div class=\"statusone\">LANDED</div></td>\n</tr>\n<tr class=\"schedulerow\" style=\"height:2px\"><td colspan=\"6\"></td></tr>\n<tr class=\"schedulerowtwo\" style=\"height:2px\"><td colspan=\"6\"></td></tr>\n<tr class=\"schedulerowtwo\" valign=\"top\">\n <td class=\"airline\"><img src=\"/webfids/images/q2.gif\" width=\"100\" height=\"24\" vspace=\"0\" alt=\"Maldivian\"/></td>\n <td class=\"flight\" nowrap>Q2 107</td>\n <td class=\"city\">Gan</td>\n <td class=\"time\">19:35</td>\n <td class=\"estimated\">19:30</td>\n <td class=\"status\"><div class=\"statusone\">LANDED</div></td>\n</tr></table>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element firstDateCell = doc.select("td.sumheadtop").first();

if (firstDateCell == null) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Unable to locate rows...");
}

System.out.println(firstDateCell.text());
for (Element aRow : firstDateCell.parent().siblingElements()) {
    if (!aRow.select("td.sumheadtop").isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(aRow.text());
    } else {
        // Handle the row now...
        System.out.println(">> " + aRow.text());
    }
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
Friday 18 March 2016
>>  PASSENGER ARRIVALS | DOMESTIC & INTERNATIONAL | All Airlines | ALL OriginS
>> 
>> 3U 8989 Chengdu 19:00 20:01 LANDED
>> 
>> 
>> Q2 107 Gan 19:35 19:30 LANDED
Saturday 19 March 2016
>>  PASSENGER ARRIVALS | DOMESTIC & INTERNATIONAL | All Airlines | ALL OriginS
>> 
>> 3U 8989 Chengdu 19:00 20:01 LANDED
>> 
>> 
>> Q2 107 Gan 19:35 19:30 LANDED
```

However, the above code displays the rows after `Saturday 19 March 2016`. You can add a break to prevent this.